# Customize color of reference graph in DbVisualizer

Tags: graph, entity-relationship, erd, dbvisualizer, schemaspy

Is it somehow possible to create differenet colored groups in the reference graph of DbVisualizer Free 9.1?

For Example:
I have table user and roles, category and pictures and each picture is related to an user, but  user and roles "boxes" in the diagramm should be shown in green and the other two in red.

I hope you understand me :)

PS: If it is possible in SchemaSpy, it would be also nice to know :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure the appearance of tables in the references graph in DbVisualizer. We have an open ticket to allow this.